# How to retain order in XML Array to Hash conversion?

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, nokogiri, savon

I'm trying to parse XML in Ruby using Nori, which internally uses Nokogiri.
The XML has some tags repeated and the library parses repeated tags as Arrays and non-repeated tags as normal elements (Hash)

```
<nodes>
  <foo>
    <name>a</name>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <name>b</name>
  </bar>
  <baz>
    <name>c</name>
  </baz>
  <foo>
    <name>d</name>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <name>e</name>
  </bar>
</nodes>
```

is parsed as

```
{nodes: {
  foo: [{name: "a"}, {name: "d"}],
  bar: [{name: "b"}, {name: "e"}],
  baz: {name: "c"}
}}
```

How do i retain the order of elements in the resulting hash like the output below?

```
{nodes: [
      {foo: {name: "a"}}, 
      {bar: {name: "b"}},
      {baz: {name: "c"}},
      {foo: {name: "d"}},
      {bar: {name: "e"}},
    ]}
```

(This may be a library specific question. But the intention is to know if anyone has faced a similar issue and how to parse it correctly)

Comment: I don't see what the desired output would be. Remember that hashes can't have multiple values with the same key.

Comment: Updated question with expected output

Answer (score 1):

Nori can't do this on its own. What you can do is tune the Nori output like this:

```
input = {nodes: {
  foo: [{name: "a"}, {name: "d"}],
  bar: [{name: "b"}, {name: "e"}],
  baz: {name: "c"}
}}

def unfurl(hash)
  out=[]
  hash.each_pair{|k,v|
    case v
    when Array
      v.each{|item|
        out << {k => item}
      }
    else
      out << {k => v}
    end
  }
  return out
end

output = {:nodes => unfurl(input[:nodes])}

puts output.inspect
```

This prints the output that the original question requested which is different than the XML order:

```
{nodes: [
  {foo: {name: "a"}}, 
  {foo: {name: "d"}},
  {bar: {name: "b"}},
  {bar: {name: "e"}},
  {baz: {name: "c"}},
]}
```

Comment: I would still be losing the original order in the XMLs this way. To retain order, i need to unfurl using both the xml and the hash

Comment: Can you say more about the order you want? The script I posted generates the order you requested (which is different than the order of the elements in the XML doc).

Comment: I made a mistake in the question. The order i expected is [foo1, bar1, baz1, foo2, bar2]. And if there's a way to retain order without referring back to original xml